# Difference between "python3 -m test" and "python3 -m unittest"

Tags: python, python-unittest

I found out that I can discover and run unit tests under my directory tree by doing this:

```
python3 -m test
```

The above works, but the [documented method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) to discover and run all tests finds hundreds more, including a new one that was not found by the previous method:

```
python3 -m unittest
```

What exactly is `-m test` and why can't I find documentation on it after a quick search, except the following page which seems to be about CPython?

https://devguide.python.org/runtests/

Comment: Did you mean https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`test`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html) package is intended to test the Python API itself. According to the documentation:

> **Note:** The `test` package is meant for internal use by Python only. It is documented for the benefit of the core developers of Python. Any use of this package outside of Python’s standard library is discouraged as code mentioned here can change or be removed without notice between releases of Python.

The link to this documentation appears in [the TOC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) under [Development Tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/development.html). While it is not entirely surprising that the `python3 -m test` command discovers and runs tests, it is not really designed to discover and run the tests that you write for your own code.